# En lista de listas sumar un valor a un elemento de una lista, según el valor de otro elemento

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente listas de listas m, si en m[1][1]==9, entonces quiero sumarle 1 al elemento que se encuentra en la casilla m[2][2]=8. Pero me sale:IndexError: list index out of range . Si intento hacer otra operación es decir, en vez de sumar, restar o multiplicar el elemento, si lo hace. No comprende porque?. Agradezco comentario.

````
m=[[1,2,3],
   [4,9,5],
   [6,10,8]]


for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m[0])):
        if m[i][j]==9:
            m[i+1][j+1]=m[i+1][j+1]+1                  
            
            
print(m)```
````

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Explicación: Primero te encuentras con la casilla `m[1][1]`, que tiene un 9. Por tanto, le sumas uno a la casilla `m[2][2]`. Como esta tenía un 8, ahora queda con un 9.

La iteración sigue hasta llegar al elemento `m[2][2]`, y como es 9, intentas modificar el elemento `m[3][3]`, que no existe:

```
    if m[i][j] == 9:  # Falla cuando m[2][2] == 9
        m[i + 1][j + 1] = m[i + 1][j + 1] + 1
```

Solución: recorrer en orden inverso, de modo de no afectar las celdas por revisar.

#### Demo

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 9, 5],
     [6, 10, 8]]

for i in range(len(m) - 1, -1, -1):
    for j in range(len(m[0]) - 1, -1, -1):
        if m[i][j] == 9:
            m[i + 1][j + 1] = m[i + 1][j + 1] + 1

print(m)
```

produce

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 9, 5], [6, 10, 9]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```